# ffmpeg not working on command line

Tags: linux, command-line, ffmpeg, centos

Code: `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 output.webm`

Error:

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.15 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers                                     
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)                                                
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpe
g --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIF
Y_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -m
tune=generic' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro ' --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --en
able-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa
 --enable-libass --enable-libcdio --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree --disable-inde
v=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopenjpeg --e
nable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-lib
theora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-x
11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enab
le-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudet
ect                                                                                                     
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100                                                                
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100                                                                
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101                                                                
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100                                                                
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101                                                                
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0                                                                
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101                                                                
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101                                                                
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100                                                                
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':                                                    
  Metadata:                                                                                             
    major_brand     : mp42                                                                              
    minor_version   : 0                                                                                 
    compatible_brands: isommp42                                                                         
    creation_time   : 2015-07-20 20:21:22                                                               
  Duration: 00:01:53.71, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 514 kb/s                                             
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x360 [SAR 1:1 
DAR 4:3], 416 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)                                  
    Metadata:                                                                                           
      handler_name    : VideoHandler                                                                    
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 95 kb/s (default)    
    Metadata:                                                                                           
      creation_time   : 2015-07-20 20:21:22                                                             
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011                                     
'NULL @ 0x12c22a0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'output.webm
: Invalid argument
```

I have php-ffpmeg and it works, but the ffmpeg command is not working on command line in my Centos 7.

Answer (score 1):

Per Gyan's comment: You should check to make sure that the your build supports webm muxing. It should be listed with as a muxer when you list formats.

```
ffmpeg -formats
```

If it is not, you can enable it when you compile using `--enable-muxer=webm`.

It seems like your build of FFmpeg is missing `--enable-libvpx`, which is needed to encode vp8 and vp9. The webm container can only hold those two video types.

As a quick fix, you could download a Linux static build from the FFmpeg site. The `ffmpeg` executable will have to be in your system path for others applications to use it. And you would want to remove the installed FFmpeg rpm package.

Depending on your setup, it might be better to compile and install FFmpeg with the included options that you require.

Comment: *Unable to find a suitable output format* is not related to encoders, even though the OP will encounter that issue once this is resolved.

Comment: Good point. I'll try to tend to it.

Comment: There was no `--disable-` configuration option used to disable the webm muxer, so `--enable-muxer=webm` is not needed.